# Which XFINITY WiFi hotspot service - Use 'xfinitywifi' or 'CafeExpress' or 'XFINITY' network to use?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

The [*XFINITY WiFi by Comcast*](http://wifi.xfinity.com) hotspot service has an app with a Help file that shows a screenshot saying:

> You can also select any network listed above the Available Networks option as shown in this example:

[image: screenshot of menu offering ‘xfinitywifi’, ‘CafeExpress’, and ’XFINITY’ items]

Usually all I see is the first item, ‘xfinitywifi’. Oddly, as I hold down the wifi menu the other two items, ‘CafeExpress’ and ’XFINITY’, occasionally pop-up briefly. As shown in that screenshot, only the third has a closed padlock icon.

Questions:

- What is the difference between these items? Is one preferable to the other?
- Why do the second and third pop-up and disappear?
- Does installing the `XFINITY WiFi` app on my Mac affect this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Well let me answer those questions as best as i can.

What is the difference between these items? Is one preferable to the other?

- The difference mainly being the fact is is a different wireless network. The "xfinitywifi" is the name of the network for xfinity users/guests. Where as the "CafeExpress" & "XFINITY" networks are private. "XFINITY" is secured, which is why it has a padlock on it, where as the other two are open networks.

Why do the second and third pop-up and disappear?

- They may be disappearing and reappearing because of the location of the router, you may be picking the signal up, then losing it

Does installing the XFINITY WiFi app on my Mac affect this situation?

- I could not tell you for sure, mainly because I have never used the app before. But, the only thing that it should change is the fact that it will automatically connect to the correct wireless network for you

I also found this webpage while searching for a few things, it may also be able to better explain the xfinity networks.

https://customer.xfinity.com/help-and-support/internet/secure-vs-open-xfinity-wifi/

I hope this helps a little :)

Comment: You are suggesting that neighbors happened to create the exact same names as used in the XFINITY documentation? Seems unlikely, especially as the Help shows a different menu with many arbitrary SSID names. The Help then separately shows the screenshot I included in my Question. So it seems to me that all three intended to be broadcast by Comcast.

Comment: I know that both "xfinitywifi" and "XFINITY" are used by Comcast, But I don't know about the third, I have never seen it when I am connecting to xfinity networks.

And yes, I MAY be suggesting that your neighbors created the exact same names for their wireless networks, I and several other people I know do it too. Gotta have some fun with your own networks.